# Vimeo player: cannot change playback speed with library @vimeo/player

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am using the library of the vimeo player https://github.com/vimeo/player.js.
My code is something like this:

```
<div id="handstick"></div>
```

```
import Player from '@vimeo/player';

const player = new Player('handstick', {
    id: 19231868,
    speed: true
});
```

But, in the player, user cannot change the speed (it was working till few days ago). On the bottom right of the video, user can only change the quality but not the speed.
Have anyone experienced this issue?

`"@vimeo/player": "^2.19.0"`